# Download multiple files with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

im trying to get 2 files from my firebase storage, they are in a folder called Ara , so the files there are 2  xxx.txt and yyy.txt  (lets call them this way)

so for testing i just run this method

```
 private void traerPictosFirebase(){

        File localFile = null;
        try {
            localFile = File.createTempFile("xxx","txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mStorageRef.child("Archivos_Paises/Ara").getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


//here i want to know if i downloaded succefully the file and find the path of it

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });



    }
```

So, now i want to do 2 things, first one is how i know if the file was downloaded to my device, in the `onSuccess` and second i want to donwload the two files, not just one

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the `onSuccess()` callback was even invoked indicates that the file was successfully downloaded.  You don't need any other confirmation.

If you want to download two files, then you'll need to make two calls to `getFile()` and deal with both of their tasks.

Comment: hi, i figured it out, yes, thanks for the advice bud !